# Github's Windows application versus Git-1.7.11 (aka MSYSGit)

Tags: windows, git, github, msysgit

I was using [MSYSGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). Recently installed [Github's Windows application](http://windows.github.com/). It crashed 1-2 times while "extracting the GIT. Please wait" screen. Then worked. I got some questions

1. Is there any chance that these 2 git's conflicting with each other? Maybe Github's application crashing because of MSYSGit?
2. I'm working with MSYSGit in daily life with DropBox. I wonder if both of them do same things? (I mean has same functionality.) If yes, can I delete MSYSGit and leave only Git's one? BTW, It has shell too. (Actually I didn't tested if it can do git procedures or not)

   [image]

Comment: hi, it's better if you ask one question per post

Comment: @CharlesB, Hi, Thx mate, for your advise. But I think, they are easy questions for git users. I'm new to git.

Comment: @epic_syntax Sorry, but whether or not they are simple questions is irrelevant. Please break up your question or choose one. The purpose of this site is to create a collection of great question/answer pairs for people ***to revisit***. Not just for your one-time use

Comment: As per @CharlesB's question, we prefer that you ask one question at a time. Also your third question isn't really suitable here, you'd be as well asking the maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github for Windows is bundled with MsysGit, so you can certainly keep only Github's.

MsysGit isn't considered stable because it has some limitations that are still worked out.

Comment: but github's version has only shell. No gui map like MSYSGit provides.

Comment: What is a GUI map?

Comment: @PeeHaa I mean hierarchial commit history map http://screencast.com/t/tIy5XrMPgvg0

Comment: I think you're referring to `gitk`.